# Are there any good graphical Git and Hg/Mercurial clients on Mac OS X?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, client, dvcs

I'm searching for compelling Git and Mercurial clients on Mac OS X. The most clients I've found so far were less compelling as I expected. Some of the clients are programmed even in Ruby or Tcl/Tk, which IMO aren't good OS X citizens in regard of integration in the OS.

I have clients similar to Versions.app or Cornetstone in mind, which are Subversion-only clients. Perhaps somebody got an insider tip for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just thought I'd mention that [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) is a Mac OS X client for *both* Mercurial and Git, in one tool. I wasn't sure if you were looking for that, or just mentioned both because you hadn't decided which to use yet; personally as an open source developer / user, having both available in one tool is very useful to me (that's why I wrote it :))

Comment: Just want to point out that SourceTree is not only free now, but available on Windows, too!

Answer (score 35):

For Mercurial, you should take a look at [**MacHg**](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/). It's free and open source. It uses the native GUI toolkit for Mac and comes with its own bundled version of Mercurial. It is very polished:

[image: State after a merge in MacHg]
<sub>(source: [jasonfharris.com](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/sceenshots/files/collage_lb_image_page6_12_1.png))</sub>

There are [many more screenshots](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/sceenshots/sceenshots.html) available.

I've also heard many good things about [**SourceTree**](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which is both a Git and a Mercurial client. Atlassian (owners of [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)) bought it recently and are now offering it as a free download.

Answer (score 11):

I started a 21-day trial of SourceTree a couple of days ago (first public release was October 26th). I already prefer it to the other three well-known Mac OS GUIs for Mercurial, but I'm new to Mercurial and therefore not a power user. It most closely resembles Murky. It was very easy to get it up and running and its balance between features and simplicity suits my tastes very well.

I have no association with the developer other than being very happy with how quickly he's been responding to the issues I've raised.

http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/home

Comment: SourceTree is especially good because it work almost the same way  with both Hg and Git.

Answer (score 8):

The main cocoa git gui apps are [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html) and [gitnub](http://wiki.github.com/Caged/gitnub)... But I figure you've already seen them... Do you have specific issues with them?

(edit - granted, neither of these can perform a `git clone` yet; they take over after a clone is created...)

[A recent comparison of OSX Git clients](http://theappleblog.com/2009/03/10/using-git-with-os-x-6-tools-to-get-you-up-and-running/)

Comment: Gitx and git nub can't be used for working on Mercurial repositories that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 8):

For a graphical Mercurial client on Mac OS X, take a look at [Murky](http://mooseyard.com/Jens/2009/04/murky-a-mercurial-client-app/).

I typically use the command line along with BBEdit for viewing my diffs.

Enable the extdiff extension by adding the following line to the [extensions] section of your .hgrc file:

```
extdiff=
```

Then add a section below

```
[extdiff]
cmd.bbdiff = bbdiff
opts.bbdiff = --wait --resume
```

Now when you execute `hg bbdiff` the changed files will be diffed one at a time in BBEdit.

Answer (score 8):

There is another new visual git client for OS X: [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/)

[image: Tower app for Mac OS X]

Answer (score 7):

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html  IS AWESOME!!

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, there's nothing with the polish of Versions or Cornerstone for git, Mercurial or Bazaar yet.  Maybe someone will change that in the future, but for right now if you want a graphical client you'll have to settle for something like GitX or Murky.

Answer (score 2):

It's commercial but I use Araxis Merge. I've used it on Windows, there's a very similar clone called Meld for Linux which I've used for years and the Mac version is very solid too.

It's pretty handy to have the same (or very nearly the same) too on all three platforms.

I'm more familiar with Mercurial than git so I'm very comfortable recommending it with Hg. As an aside, I'm guessing that you know how the hg extdiff command works but if not post a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Now [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/) project ports to Mac OS X. It uses Qt+ as GUI toolkit, so it works on major platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking specifically about Versions, other people haven't found this, but I've experienced a lot of crashes with it. Murky had a big crash the first time I used it, but the author makes it clear he's releasing it 'as-is' and that it works for him, and TortoiseHg is the last one I'd try (and am trying) because I'm used to it crashing on the PC side.

Murky looks about as good as anything, however, and has some good UI design. Depends if you want shell integration however.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completness, it should be mentioed that Apples Xcode 4 now also got support for git as a SVM. It's far from perfect but it does the basic functionality quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Git**

Colleague has had good experiences with [GitBox](http://www.gitboxapp.com/).

[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) wins on windows from what i have seen, nothing else is comparable. It may be a bit strange at first sometimes. 
(i.e. FETCH is not directly available, instead you have to PULL and choose in the popup window not to merge directly. Once you know that it is no problem.)
It also has a nice graphical log viewer.

SmartGit is multiplatform, so it will work everywhere quite the same, and thus would be my recommendation in a multi-OS environment.

**hg**

Sorry, no experience on mac with it.