# What are some good Mercurial GUI clients for OS X?

Tags: macos, user-interface, mercurial

I really like the Brotherbard GitX fork; is there something along the same lines for hg?

Comment: Dangit, I wish there was a "vote to not close".

Comment: re: close voters - there is a similar question on OS X Git GUIs and it's not even CW! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83789/what-is-the-best-git-gui-on-osx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any good graphical git and hg/Mercurial clients on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081965/are-there-any-good-graphical-git-and-hg-mercurial-clients-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 20):

[Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) has a good clean GUI and supports Mercurial and Git and it's free.

Comment: It seems to be free by now, after Atlassian bought it in support for their other sold products.

Comment: I've been using SourceTree for about a year, although now I'm on the hunt for something else.  My main problem is performance, sourcetree is quite slow compared to just using command line. So much so that all I use sourcetree for now is to visualize the tree.

Comment: sourcetree on Mavericks crashes a lot recently

Comment: Sourcetree's shelve works very differently from from the shelve/stash of hg/git. When you shelve changes in a branch, change branches and unshelve, you actually get a merge(!). Extremely annoying and may cause a lot of manual labor.. This alone (+ some other inconsistencies) makes Sourcetree a no-starter for me (for Mercurial, with git there seems to be no issues). I need to be able to trust the tools I use, especially when it comes to version control.

Answer (score 11):

[MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg) is a fairly full OSX client:

It is a native OSX GUI client for Mercurial. It is modern and fully multi-threaded using Grand Central Dispatch and threading goodness. It has a clean interface and allows multiple repositories per document, using a standard mac sidebar interface. It incrementally loads data so its very fast. Ie it easily handles browsing the mozilla repository which is 3.35Gb. MacHg is fully featured handling all standard Mercurial commands, and additionally provides history editing features through the Mercurial rebase, strip, collapse, and histedit extensions.

Comment: MacHg doesn't remember which repos you were tracking last.  So if you reboot your machine, you'll have to re-open the repos.  Kinda user-unfriendly...

Answer (score 6):

[Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) is about it, but it's nowhere near as mature as GitX.

Comment: How can this possibly be the only viable option on MacOS X?

Answer (score 2):

[TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home) is an OK GUI.  OSX port is reported as "in progress."

Comment: I can't stress enough how much you should avoid this answer

Comment: ditto. THg is ace on Windows but doesn't run on Mac

Answer (score 1):

I use Murky. There are two things to note:

1. When you enter the repository url use this pattern: https://username:password@domain.com. That's the only place where you can enter your username and password.
2. There are some things you can't do through the GUI (I think merge is one of them), in which case you can launch the terminal from the app and use the command line. You'll then see any changes update in the GUI.